# web.xml ignoring main JSP file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to create a servlet which loads "FirstJSP.jsp" in WEB-INF/jsp/FirstJSP.jsp

I'm having a problem with my web.xml file. I've looked through dozens of forum posts both on SO and elsewhere, yet none of them work.

Here's my current revision

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Queue</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/jsp/FirstJSP.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Queue</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstJSP.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is a screenshot to show the file hierarchy. I think I've tried about every method possible, so there must be something very simple I am missing :) Thank you.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why do you want to map a jsp page as a servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess JSPs should be outside the WEB-INF. You may see an example here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html

or even better, here: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/gexap.html

Comment: Yes!! the Google Code link did the trick. Unfortunately, I still have no idea what fixed it, as I'd like to learn. Putting it outside the WEB-INF folder was part of it, but there must have been another change in the web.xml file. I'll figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: I wonder if the solution could have had anything to do with the order of each element. Would it matter that the <welcome-file> element came last?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz  The order does not matter. However, Eclipse does complain if order is not right. The order is as follows: icon?,display-name?,description?,distributable?,context-
 param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-
 list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-
 entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref* Where ? => zero or one, * => zero or more

Answer (score 1):

Your css and jsp folders should be out of WEB-INF directory as this directory will be locked (when you want direct access to your jsp files, which I think you want) and you **don't** need to map JSP files :) 
You should remove `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` from your web.xml

Comment: Thanks, Premraj. I moved the /jsp folder and its contents to /WebContent but I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks again for the updated answer, Premaj. But removing <servlet> and <servlet-mapping>? isn' that the entire file?

Comment: yes the web.xml will be empty(with only `<web-app>` tag) unless you have servlets, filters or listeners or other settings like error page and etc to put in.