# Web.xml causes Tomcat7 to fail

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a basic servlet.

I using tomcat 7 to run it.

The server contains 3 files:

1. file.jsp - prints the date
2. WebController - the servlet.
3. web.xml - configuration file.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
          <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
          <jsp-file>file.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I remove the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` from the `web.xml` file, the servlet runs good.

When `web.xml` is as the above, I'm getting the following error message:

```
'Staring Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.

Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

I'm using eclipse. what is the problem in my `web.xml` file? thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is my project:

[image]

Update:

current version of `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
          <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
          <jsp-file>/file.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WebController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>WebController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642745/web-xml-ignoring-main-jsp-file
where did you put the jsp files

Comment: @ph. the jsp file is in the same folder with `web.xml`, in `WEB-INF` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your jsp file must not be in WEB-INF.
Place it in the root of your project

Update the `web.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
      <jsp-file>/file.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>file.jsp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

here is how your project should look like:

```
/myjspapp
   /file.jsp
   /WEB-INF
      /web.xml
```

you can now access your jsp at the following url: `localhost:8080/myjspapp/about`

Comment: Now it is not recognized, HTTP Status 500 - missing jspFile: [/file.jsp]

Comment: I've updated my post and attached a picture with my project, can you please tell me what's still wrong?

I have the same `xml.web` as you put, but I'm getting `HTTP Status 500 - missing jspFile: [/file.jsp]` when accessing `http://localhost:8080/WebCoupons/about`

Comment: do you have the ` <jsp-file>/file.jsp</jsp-file>` (with the slash) in `web.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my post and attached the current version of `web.xml`.

Comment: and what says the stacktrace when you deploy?

Comment: description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: You'll may think I'm jocking on you back moving the jsp files to the `WebContent` folder has solve it. thanks you for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

One possible format for servlet mapping in the `web.xml` file looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.example.file_jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.file_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.example.file_jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/file.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The class name comes from the JSP file name and this part of your build.xml:

```
<jasper2 
  validateXml="false"
  uriroot="web"
  package="com.example"
  webXmlFragment="build/web/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml"
  outputDir="build/src" />
```

Comment: The OP does not mapped `Servlet`, he is mapping `JSP` file.

Comment: I've been pre-compiling my JSP for so long I honestly forgot there was another way :P (I removed the "correct way", but left the answer in case it's helpful)

Answer (score 0):

**This is answer is similar to as ph's but as you said that it was giving you status 500 so, worked the problem out for you...**

Try putting the JSP file in webcontent folder (For eclipse only) and then follow your example.

I have worked on your example and it gives me proper output.

**Below is my project structure in eclipse:-**

[image]

**Below is configured web.xml file:-**
[image]

After running the server, and requesting the URL Pattern "/about" I am getting my output of JSP.

Please try and let me know... Hope this helps